# is the f1-micro instance used with gae flexible environment included in free tier?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I want to host my side project using AppEngine Flexible Environment with a `f1-micro` instance. Is this instance eligible for free tier?

According to the latest [Google Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/free) it should.

However, App engine pricing calculator shows a charge of `$10.79` per month. `vCPU = 0.2, memory= 0.6GB`

[image]

Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: I'll look into this for you and post an answer once I have an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no free tier for App Engine flexible environment. [Always Free](https://cloud.google.com/free/) only includes usage limits for App Engine standard environment, not App Engine flexible environment.

The [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions) will be updated to clarify this.